# Changing the user agent of MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, user-agent, mpmovieplayer

When I request files from my server (using the simulator) my UA is listed as

```
"AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.10B141 (iPad Simulator; U; CPU OS 6_1 like Mac OS X; en_us)"
```

Is there any way I can programmatically change this to a string of my choosing?
I'm aware of how to use NSUserDefaults

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

This doesn't seem to work with the MPMoviePlayer requests though